# How to get FormControlName from Directive in mat-form-field?

Tags: angular, permissions

I have an idea to dynamicly render (on not render) elements with different formControl properties (readOnly for example). I want to get FormControlName from "mat-form-field" tag to send it to permissionService. How can I resolve it?

Directive Code:

```
import {Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';
import {PermissionService} from '../../services/auth/permission.service';
// import {ControlContainer} from "@angular/forms";

@Directive({
    selector: '[appPermission]'
})
export class PermissionDirective {

    field: string;
    
    constructor(
        private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
        // private readonly form: ControlContainer,
        private permissionService: PermissionService
    ) {
    }
    @Input() set appPermission(url: string) {
        this.checkPermission(url);
    }
    private checkPermission(url: string): void {

        if (this.permissionService.getPermission(url, field)) {
            this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        } else {
            this.viewContainer.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Template:

```
<mat-form-field *appPermission="'example.com/v1/endpoint'">
    <mat-label>Notification url</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="url" formControlName="notifyUrl" autocomplete="off">
    <mat-error>
        {{errors.cyrillicNotSupported}}
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to access FormControl in your directive, you should use `[FormControl]`.

**Template**

```
<mat-form-field [formControl]="formGroup.get('notifyUrl')" *appPermission="'example.com/v1/endpoint'">
    <mat-label>Notification url</mat-label>
    <input matInput type="url" formControlName="notifyUrl" autocomplete="off">
    <mat-error>
        {{errors.cyrillicNotSupported}}
    </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Directive**

```
import {Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core';
import {PermissionService} from '../../services/auth/permission.service';
// import {ControlContainer} from "@angular/forms";

@Directive({
    selector: '[appPermission]'
})
export class PermissionDirective {

    field: string;
    
    constructor(
        private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
        private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
        // private readonly form: ControlContainer,
        private permissionService: PermissionService
    ) {
    }
    @Input() set appPermission(url: string) {
        this.checkPermission(url);
    }
    @Input() set formControl(fc: FormControl) {
        // Do something for FormControl.
    }
    private checkPermission(url: string): void {

        if (this.permissionService.getPermission(permission, field)) {
            this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
        } else {
            this.viewContainer.clear();
        }
    }
}
```